# Conditional Vlookup 3 search terms one table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

Is there a way  I  can do  a Vlookup  with 3 different search terms  on one  table ?
Per example, I  want to  lookup by SamAcctName or UserLogonName or TestName  on  one  big pool of data

```
Search terms  

SamAcctName    |      UserLogonName     |   TestName  |      result      |
---------------|------------------------|-------------|------------------|
test.user      | testuser@test.com      | testus      | Result 1 <<<<<<  |
---------------|------------------------|-------------|------------------|
estuser        |   other@test.com       | testuseer   | Result 2 <<<<<<  |
---------------|------------------------|-------------|------------------|




Table with all data records 


Name          |        Description      |     moredata       |
--------------|-------------------------|--------------------|
Test.User     |  Result 1 <<<<<<<       |    Blah  Blah BLah |
--------------|-------------------------|--------------------|
other@test.com|  user ..Blah Blah       |    Blah  Blah BLah |
--------------|-------------------------|--------------------|
other.user    |  user ..Blah Blah       |    Blah  Blah BLah |
--------------|-------------------------|--------------------|
TestUser2     |  user ..Blah Blah       |    Blah  Blah BLah |
--------------|-------------------------|--------------------|
other.user    |  user ..Blah Blah       |    Blah  Blah BLah |
--------------|-------------------------|--------------------|
other@test.com|  Result 2 <<<<<<<       |    Blah  Blah BLah |
--------------|-------------------------|--------------------|
other.user    |  user ..Blah Blah       |    Blah  Blah BLah |
--------------|-------------------------|--------------------|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple sledgehammer approach would be to write nested `IFERROR(VLOOKUP...` like below formula.

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,F:G,2,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,F:G,2,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,F:G,2,0),"")))`

where columns F&G house all data table and the first table is in `A2:D3` range.

Answer (score 0):

`=INDEX(D1:D3,MATCH(1,MMULT(--(A1:C3=E1),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A1:C3)^0)),0))`

This is an array function to be entered with `ctrl + shift + enter`

An array is created from `A1:C3=E1` as 1 or 2 (TRUE or FALSE). The array is 3 columns and the length of your range.
A second array is created with `TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A1:C3)^0)` resulting in `{1, 2, 3}` and that to the power 0 is `{1, 1, 1}`.
MMULT multiplies these arrays and the result is the row number of your matching value.
INDEX shows the result value in your index column of that row.

Edit:  I just realised I used E1 as the lookup value, but in your situation change this to the cell applicable to you. Also the ranges of data are an assumption and may need to be modified.

To reflect your data as posted below:
Search terms are from H2 to I500 and data pool is from A2 to F1465 where my assumption is that the result data to be displayed is to come from column B:
`=INDEX(B2:B1465,MATCH(1,MMULT(--(H2:I500=A1),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(H2:I500)^0)),0))`

Comment: Thank you!  i was not able to  get this formula  working how ever   it  feels  like  an elegant aproach  .. can you tell me  what topics i need to understand to come up  with a solution like this ?

Comment: Index match combination is often better practice then vlookup, because the ability to use multiple conditions. To do so use `INDEX(Result_Range,MATCH(1,(criteria_1)*(criteria_2)*(etc.),0))` for the row number meeting all conditions to be TRUE (=1).

Comment: What is the range of your data for your first table and what for your second?

Comment: My search terms are from H2 to I500 and my data pool is a table.  From A2 to F1465.  That was one of the questions while i inputed table per name ir resulted in 0

Comment: I updated my answer to the given ranges. Let me know if it works (don't forget to enter the formula as array as described).